# Tizen Construct() Button method fails

Tags: c++, linux, tizen

Could anyone help with Tizen **Button** construction problem?

I'm getting the following log message after **Construct()** call of **Button** and application crashed. But Construct() in this case returns E_SUCCESS:

```
result Tizen::Graphics::_Text::TextObject::SetBounds(const Tizen::Graphics::FloatRectangle&)(1134) > [E_OUT_OF_RANGE] The given rectangle(width:-4.000000,height:12.000000) is out of range.
```

In the following code:

```
MainSimpleButton::MainSimpleButton()
{
    result res = Construct(FloatRectangle(50, 50, 20, 20), String("Default button"));
    if (res != E_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw Exception("Failed Construct() button");
    }
}
```

Here is details. I have customized Button class:

```
#ifndef MAINBUTTON_H_
#define MAINBUTTON_H_

#include <FApp.h>
#include <FUi.h>
#include <FGraphics.h>

class MainSimpleButton : public Tizen::Ui::Controls::Button {
public:
    MainSimpleButton(); // <------- This constructor is used
    MainSimpleButton(const Tizen::Graphics::Rectangle &rect, const Tizen::Base::String &text);
    MainSimpleButton(const Tizen::Graphics::FloatRectangle &rect, const Tizen::Base::String &text);
    virtual ~MainSimpleButton();
};

#endif /* MAINBUTTON_H_ */
```

With the following simple implementation:

```
MainSimpleButton::MainSimpleButton()
{
    result res = Construct(FloatRectangle(50, 50, 20, 20), String("Default button"));
    if (res != E_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw Exception("Failed Construct() button");
    }
}

MainSimpleButton::MainSimpleButton(const Rectangle &rect, const String &text)
{ // Similar to MainSimpleButton }

MainSimpleButton::MainSimpleButton(const FloatRectangle &rect, const String &text)
{ // Similar to MainSimpleButton }

MainSimpleButton::~MainSimpleButton() {}
```

Add instance of this customized Button() is created here:

```
void MainForm::InitMainForm(unsigned long formStyle)
{
    if (Construct(formStyle) != E_SUCCESS) { throw Exception("MainForm Construct() failed"); }
    MainSimpleButton *btn1 = new MainSimpleButton(); // <----- This code
    if (AddControl(btn1) != E_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw Exception("MainForm AddControl() failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried making the button bigger? Seems like the minimum width for a button is 24 pixels.

Comment: I had multiple modifications, before getting it work. Now sure that tested only this change separately. If I could restore environment I'll test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General it's a Tizen Framework problem.
Suggest you have UI application with one button. The application structure will be following:

```
UIApp : [ Frame : [ Form : [ Button ] ] ]
```

and the initialization call chain for this simple UI will be following:

```
OnAppInitializing():
    new Frame() => Frame.Construct() =>
    AddFrame(frame):
        Frame.OnInitializing():
            new Form() => Form.Construct() =>
            AddControl(form):
                Form.OnInitializing():
                    new Button() => Button.Construct() =>
                    AddControl(button):
                        Button.OnInitializing()
```

The reason for this: object constructor does nothing (as Tizen doesn't use exceptions) and the real job is done by **Construct()** method.
We can get the same result by using custom objects which will use constructors and exception.

```
OnAppInitializing():
    new Frame():
        Frame.Construct()
        new Form():
            Form.Construct()
            new Button():
                Button.Construct()
            AddControl(button)
         AddControl(form)
     AddFrame(frame)
```

This is what I wanted to do.

In point of view of Tizen framework we should get the same result as before every `AddFrame()/AddControl()` function call we have valid chain `new Object() => Object.Construct() => AddControl(Object)`.

But the problem, probably is that when on my phone I get the same result, log is different:

```
04-05 02:18:04.840 : ERROR / Tizen::Ui::Controls ( 16130 : 16130 ) : Tizen::Ui::Animations::_VisualElement* Tizen::Ui::Controls::_IndicatorManager::GetIndicatorVisualElement(Tizen::Ui::_Window*, Tizen::Ui::Controls::_IndicatorOrientation, Tizen::Ui::_Control*) const(132) > [E_SYSTEM] Unable to get Indicator
04-05 02:18:04.840 : ERROR / Tizen::Ui::Controls ( 16130 : 16130 ) : result Tizen::Ui::Controls::_Indicator::AddIndicatorObject(Tizen::Ui::_Control*, Tizen::Ui::_Window*)(373) > [E_SYSTEM] Indicator can not create the surface.
04-05 02:18:04.840 : ERROR / Tizen::Ui::Controls ( 16130 : 16130 ) : Tizen::Ui::Animations::_VisualElement* Tizen::Ui::Controls::_IndicatorManager::GetIndicatorVisualElement(Tizen::Ui::_Window*, Tizen::Ui::Controls::_IndicatorOrientation, Tizen::Ui::_Control*) const(132) > [E_SYSTEM] Unable to get Indicator
04-05 02:18:04.840 : ERROR / Tizen::Ui::Controls ( 16130 : 16130 ) : result Tizen::Ui::Controls::_Indicator::AddIndicatorObject(Tizen::Ui::_Control*, Tizen::Ui::_Window*)(373) > [E_SYSTEM] Indicator can not create the surface.
04-05 02:18:04.840 : ERROR / Tizen::Ui ( 16130 : 16130 ) : result Tizen::Ui::_Control::SetFocused(bool)(2634) > [E_INVALID_OPERATION] This control should have a parent or be attached to the main tree.
```

Thus I think Tizen Framework can doesn't support my approach very well.